# Can i make a total rework of my app without launching a new package name?

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to launch my app but I am afraid that at some point I will need to make a rework of the app making it all over again changing a lot of things that a simple update wouldn't be enough. My question is can I do this rework keeping my app stars and package name or I will need to do this as a new version like MyApp2 ?

Can I access the sqlite tables after this rework and update it as needed ?

Comment: I'm wondering why an update wouldn't be enough, can you explain? If you change the package you'll lost everything as a brand new app

Comment: It's *your* app you can *do what you like*. The *package name* **IS** your app. Anything else is other. People can change their votes in Play Store. *sqlite tables* are local to *package name*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can rework it entirely and just update it on the store, the app can be really different than the first one, it doesn't matter, if you want to keep your package, app stars, comments nad sqlite tables then you'll need a simple update on google play

Comment: When you mention single update in the end that includes the rework it entirely right ?

Comment: Yes @AndreAndriole, you're free to make any change in your app update, even a total rework, it's up to you! Your package name is unique for google play, if you change that you'll need to publish an brand new app